# CUDA runtime unknown error, maybe a driver problem? CUDA can't see my gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, nvidia

My code is very simple for now:

```
import torch 
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
torch.cuda.current_device()

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-3380d2c12118> in <module>
----> 1 torch.cuda.current_device()

~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py in current_device()
    349 def current_device():
    350     r"""Returns the index of a currently selected device."""
--> 351     _lazy_init()
    352     return torch._C._cuda_getDevice()
    353 

~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py in _lazy_init()
    161             "Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. " + msg)
    162     _check_driver()
--> 163     torch._C._cuda_init()
    164     _cudart = _load_cudart()
    165     _cudart.cudaGetErrorName.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (30) : unknown error at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556653099582/work/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp:51
```

Looking in the internet it looks like it is a version problem, but I swear I tried all combinations of drivers from CUDA 10.0, 10.1, tensorflow-gpu 13, 12, etc. and nothing seems to work.

NVIDIA driver: `nvidia-smi`:

```
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.14       Driver Version: 430.14       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 930MX       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   36C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    139MiB /  2004MiB |      4%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       986      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            64MiB |
|    0      1242      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          72MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

CUDA VERSION `nvcc --version` :

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
```

tensorflow-gpu version: `pip list | grep tensorflow`:

```
tensorflow                         1.13.1   
tensorflow-estimator               1.13.0
```

pytorch version `pip list | grep torch`

```
pytorch-pretrained-bert            0.6.2    
torch                              1.1.0    
torchvision                        0.3.0
```

Can anyone see a problem of compatibility and explain why and how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you try this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5777#issuecomment-301058363 ? or just rebooting

Comment: How is your problem related to tensorflow? You only showed code for PyTorch.

Comment: @BramVanroy you're right, I was thinking to upload also some tensorflow code, but then I realized it wasn't necessary.

Comment: @DSDS thanks for your answer! I didn't try, but I dropped the problem and switched to cloud computing using Google Colab, so I think I'll delete this question. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

Did you test your cuda installation ? If not you can use (which will take a while):

```
 $ cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-10.0_Samples
 $ make
```

And then:

```
$ cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-10.0_Samples/bin/x86_64/linux/release
$./deviceQuery
```

You should get "Test passed!" as result.

[Source](https://medium.com/@cjanze/how-to-install-tensorflow-with-gpu-support-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-with-cuda-10-nvidia-gpu-312a693744b5)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, probably the error is caused by the fact that installing NVIDIA drivers, it automatically installs also the CUDA driver, as you can see it has a different version from the CUDA-development-kit that I downloaded. During installation it was suggested to NOT install also the CUDA drivers, so I did. The problem is that I can't downgrade the CUDA drivers from NVIDIA and I can't install them from the CUDA-dk installer because it raises some errors (which I think are fixable but I didn't have time).
I solved everything using Google Colab instead of my personal laptop  ahahahah